# Unable to log in to Nifi and got a error message :Access Unknown: Certificate and Token not found

Tags: authentication, certificate, apache-nifi

I am facing a persistent issue where I am unable to log in to Nifi using a custom certificate and reverse proxy setup, despite modifying the keystore and passwd settings in the nifi.properties file. It is worth mentioning that I can successfully log in to Nifi using localhost. However, when attempting to access Nifi using the domain name, I continually receive the error message “Unable to log in, Access Unknown: Certificate and Token not found.” I have also ensured that the certificate is properly installed on the client-side.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on why this issue may be occurring and how it can be resolved. Your assistance is greatly appreciated!

To troubleshoot the issue, I have verified that the custom certificate is correctly installed on the client-side. However, my expectations of successfully logging in to Nifi using the customized certificate and reverse proxy setup have not been met. Instead, I consistently receive the error message “Unable to log in, Access Unknown: Certificate and Token not found.”